# How to get browser ID or any unique ID from browser which acts as device ID in laravel/JS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, browser, laravel-blade

I want a unique ID that can identify users based on their browser/machine or anything. Basically, anything that is similar to device IDs in android.

Comment: There's no such thing in a browser - why do you need such a unique identifier?

Comment: maybe an MD5 of user-agent + ip ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called [device fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) and there are real world legal implications on doing it so I suggest you check local laws of where you plan to operate before doing anything like this.

Comment: Maybe interesting in this context: https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/. For example, people using brave browser can hardly be fingerprinted